# How to import the Spring Framework sourcecode into an eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I wanted to pull in all the sourcecode from Spring into eclipse, but wasn't sure how to pull all those multiple projects into one eclipse project.  Anyone know how to set this up?

Comment: Do you want to have a extra eclipse project to compile it, or you you just want to attach the source to the spring jars, so that you can have a look at it on a normal project?

Comment: I just want to attach the source so I can look at the code as a normal project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/03/building-spring-3/

Comment: Kudos to you Chris for this one!  Your way is much better. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use Maven. So if your project is a maven project, then eclipse with M2Eclipse plugin (or STS where the plugin is already included) will provide this service for you automatically.

If you don't use Maven, then eclipse allowes you to attach the source code to every used jar by hand. (Select the jar in the package explorer, right click, Java Source Attachment). I guess you can download the sources somewhere from Spring. Or you can download it from a maven repository with your browser for example form here: http://search.maven.org/#browse|528292745

*When I remember right, then you can also use `window/preference/java/build path/user libaries` to define the source attachments for jars. The purpose of this way is, that you will not need to do it for each project again and again.*

Answer (score 2):

Take source code and add it to your eclipse workspace.

**Click on your project (Right Click) -> Debug As -> Debug Configuration -> Source Tab**

Add one or more projects by click add button. Achives, Directories supported as well.

Alternatively you can add break point in your code, hit F5 to go into spring code and eclipse will prompt you to add source code.